# Kendo UI Web - MultiSelect: select an option more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I'm currently facing a problem with the Kendo UI `MultiSelect` widget for selecting an option more than once. For example, in the image below I want to select *Schindler's List* again after selecting *The Dark Knight*, but unfortunately the `MultiSelect` widget behaves more like a set than an ordered list, i.e. repetitive selection is not allowed. Is there actually a proper way to achieve this? Any workarounds?

[image: kmultiselect-repetitiveselectionfailed]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the intended behavior of the multi-select control and there is no simple way to make it do what you want using the available configuration options. Possible workarounds are ...

### Creating a custom multi-select widget

Something like this should work (note that I haven't tested this much - it lets you add multiples and keeps the filter intact though):

```
(function ($) {
    var ui = kendo.ui,
        MultiSelect = ui.MultiSelect;

    var originalRender = MultiSelect.fn._render;
    var originalSelected = MultiSelect.fn._selected;

    var CustomMultiSelect = MultiSelect.extend({
        init: function (element, options) {
            var that = this;

            MultiSelect.fn.init.call(that, element, options);
        },

        options: {
            name: 'CustomMultiSelect'
        },

        _select: function (li) {
            var that = this,
                values = that._values,
                dataItem,
                idx;

            if (!that._allowSelection()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!isNaN(li)) {
                idx = li;
            } else {
                idx = li.data("idx");
            }

            that.element[0].children[idx].selected = true;

            dataItem = that.dataSource.view()[idx];

            that.tagList.append(that.tagTemplate(dataItem));
            that._dataItems.push(dataItem);
            values.push(that._dataValue(dataItem));

            that.currentTag(null);
            that._placeholder();

            if (that._state === "filter") {
                that._state = "accept";
            }
            console.log(this.dataSource.view());
        },        

        _render: function (data) {
            // swapping out this._selected keeps filtering functional
            this._selected = dummy;  
            return originalRender.call(this, data);
            this._selected = originalSelected;
        }
    });

    function dummy() { return null; }

    ui.plugin(CustomMultiSelect);
})(jQuery);
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/h58Db/).

### Using a dropdown list

Use a simple dropdown list (or ComboBox) and bind the select event to append to your list (which you have to create manually).

For example:

```
var mySelectedList = [];
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    select: function (e) {
        var item = e.item;
        var text = item.text();
        // store your selected item in the list
        mySelectedList.push({
            text: text
        });
        // update the displayed list
        $("#myOrderedList").append("<li>" + text + "</li>");
    }
});
```

Then you could bind clicks on those list elements to remove elements from the list. The disadvantage of that is that it requires more work to make it look "pretty" (you have to create and combine your own HTML, css, images etc.).

Comment: The first "hack" works like a charm for me. Thanks for your efforts! But, I guess I'd rather go with the second workaround for the moment, because, as you said, it's supposed to be the intended behavior of the HTML multi-select element.

Comment: @GlennMohammad I think this answer was accepted at one point; did any problems crop up with my solution?

Comment: I was almost positive that I accepted your answer right away, but back then I was in hurry for vacation and turned out I pushed the wrong button. Apologize, and I fix it now.

Comment: No problem, I was just wondering because I remembered that too. Thanks for fixing it.